# Styles and Scripts not Loading After URL-Rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have applied a URL-rewrite rule to my web-site using `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter.dll` extension. On the web.config file I have written rules like the following:

```
<add name="Default"
     virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/Default.zkn"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/Default.aspx?lang=$1"
     ignoreCase="true"
/>
```

It easily changes `http://sitename.com/en/Default.zkn` to Default.aspx?lang=en

A part of my `head` section is like the following:

```
<link href="Styles/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

But since I have applied this, The styles and the additional javascript files pointed relatively on the `head` section are not loaded.

Then I have tried to add `~` character.

```
<link href="~/Styles/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

Many people said this would work. But no, it did not work.

After page loads I open the source on the browser and I see that `~` character was not replaced with my site folder.

So a 404 error occurs for the css and js files.

How can it be corrected?

Is there a way to add a new URL-rewriting rule for the style/js files also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
<%
var basePath = String.Format("{0}{1}",Request.ApplicationPath,  string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ApplicationPath) || !Request.ApplicationPath.EndsWith("/") ? "/" : "");
%>

<link href="<%=basePath%>Styles/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" />
```