# Why does ~/ not work inside script references?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using jQuery for my ASP.NET project. I just realized, that it does only work, if the navigation depth is not as deep. For example

- `http://localhost/myapp/index/` works
- `http://localhost/myapp/index/sites/sub/` does not work

The error I encountered was caused by jQuery. Firebug told me, that

> `$` is not defined.

After some research, I changed my meta definitions like this:

```asp
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Css/style.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Still, it did not work. After I took a look into the server response, the `href` of the CSS link got replaced correctly:

```asp
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Css/style.css" />
```

However, for my script ressources the relative path hasn't been replaced:

```asp
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I expected something like `../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js`.

Is this wanted behaviour? How should I setup application root references for script resources, correctly? Would writing `/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` work when I am hosting my website as web application in IIS?

Comment: Is this WebForms or MVC?

Comment: If webforms aren't you missing a `runat=server` on all the elements you are using the `~` with?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I am on WebForms!

Comment: @MartinSmith: Afaik, you can't add `runat="server"` to a `script` tag, can't you?!

Comment: @Aschratt - Years since I've used web forms but as far as I remember you have to if you want it to parse the `~` and rewrite the path correctly.

Comment: Look into the [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) or [`Bundles`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx).

Comment: @MartinSmith: Tested it, but throws an parser error. Also in my CSS-links the `~/` gets replaced correctly without `runat="server"`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Romoku: What should I find there?

Comment: I guess this might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16209096/1236044

Comment: @jbl: Thanks for your research. This looks like a fairly simple workaround. However I am still interested if this is a bug, wanted behaviour, or whatever else. :)

Comment: this is wanted behaviour. "~" is part of the asp.net syntax, it is not meant to be placed and interpreted directly in html markup

Comment: @jbl: this isn't what I am trying. I do not want to place it inside the HTML response. I've located the tags of my question inside the masterfile. Shouldn't it get resolved then?

Comment: html elements are not interpreted by asp.net, unless they are runat="server", in which case, "some parts" (depending on the element) might be interpreted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Page.ResolveUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) to link to your resources instead:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Css/style.css")%>" />
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.uniform.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will resolve to the parent directory of your website, whether it's hosted as the root of the application or even a virtual directory.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! However I still would like to prefer an answer, that describes *why* `~/` does not work for `script` resources, but for `link`s.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the way <script> tags are rendered by .NET. It appears it's a known 'issue', but I can't find any reason as to why it is. http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/the_script_tag_runatserver_problem_solution_using_resolveurl.aspx